# Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic-invoke

Let's say that I have a table named `Poll` and I want to write a LINQ Extension to list all polls that have ID belong to an array. For e.g:

```
void Main()
{
    long[] ids = new long[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    ListFail<Poll>(Poll, p => p.ID, ids); //Failed!
    ListOK<Poll>(Poll, p => p.ID, ids); //OK!
}

public void ListFail<T>(Table<T> obj, Func<T, long> idProperty, long[] ids) where T : class
{
    obj.Where(p => ids.Contains(idProperty(p))).ToList().Dump();
}

public void ListOK<T>(Table<T> obj, Func<T, long> idProperty, long[] ids) where T : class
{
    obj.ToList().Where(p => ids.Contains(idProperty(p))).ToList().Dump();
}
```

I don't know why I get the error on `ListFail`

```
Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

and when I added the `ToList()` before `Where` then it run well on `ListOK` but of course I don't want to get the whole `Poll` table.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Change `Func<T, long>` to `Expression<Func<T, long>>`. Right now, because of this, EF doesn't understand it.

Comment: I've changed it according to your suggestion but got another error `'idProperty' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'`

Comment: I'm sorry. I cant help you. Query composition can be ass sometimes and this looks like it wont be easy to implement. One thing that comes to mind is to create the expression tree by hand. But I dont have time for that.